# Failed resolution of: Lcom/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/cognitoauth/handlers/AuthHandler;

Tags: android, aws-sdk, google-signin, aws-amplify

I configured Google signin and AWS identity pool. I am trying to setup **google sigin without AWS signin UI**.After loggedin successfully with google,I am trying to access AWSMobileClient API in android,but I can't access this API I don't know what is wrong in my code. There is an exception which crashes my app.

My code is here

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().federatedSignIn(IdentityProvider.GOOGLE.toString(), googleSignInAccount.getIdToken(), new Callback<UserStateDetails>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(UserStateDetails result) {
            showToast("sigin in success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    });
```

Detailed Exception:

```
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.I/ugdroid.awstes: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$10>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/cognitoauth/handlers/AuthHandler;
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.getInstance() (AWSMobileClient.java:-1)
    at void com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.signInToAws(com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount) (MainActivity.java:59)
    at void com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.handleGoogleSiginInIntent(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task) (MainActivity.java:86)
    at void com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent) (MainActivity.java:78)
    at void android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(java.lang.String, int, int, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (Activity.java:7462)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, java.util.List, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:4391)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(android.os.IBinder, java.util.List, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:4440)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(android.app.ClientTransactionHandler, android.os.IBinder, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions) (ActivityResultItem.java:49)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
    at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:193)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoauth.handlers.AuthHandler" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thu
    at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.getInstance() (AWSMobileClient.java:-1)
    at void com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.signInToAws(com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount) (MainActivity.java:59)
    at void com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.handleGoogleSiginInIntent(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task) (MainActivity.java:86)
    at void com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent) (MainActivity.java:78)
    at void android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(java.lang.String, int, int, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (Activity.java:7462)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, java.util.List, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:4391)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(android.os.IBinder, java.util.List, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:4440)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(android.app.ClientTransactionHandler, android.os.IBinder, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions) (ActivityResultItem.java:49)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
    at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:193)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:858)
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$10>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/cognitoauth/handlers/AuthHandler;
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.getInstance() (AWSMobileClient.java:-1)
    at void com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.signInToAws(com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount) (MainActivity.java:59)
    at void com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.handleGoogleSiginInIntent(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task) (MainActivity.java:86)
    at void com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent) (MainActivity.java:78)
    at void android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(java.lang.String, int, int, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (Activity.java:7462)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, java.util.List, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:4391)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(android.os.IBinder, java.util.List, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:4440)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(android.app.ClientTransactionHandler, android.os.IBinder, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions) (ActivityResultItem.java:49)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
    at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:193)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoauth.handlers.AuthHandler" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thugdroid.awstest-z3VQ3OBLMKt2xmXSalamxg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.thu
    at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.getInstance() (AWSMobileClient.java:-1)
    at void com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.signInToAws(com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount) (MainActivity.java:59)
    at void com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.handleGoogleSiginInIntent(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task) (MainActivity.java:86)
    at void com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent) (MainActivity.java:78)
    at void android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(java.lang.String, int, int, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (Activity.java:7462)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, java.util.List, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:4391)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(android.os.IBinder, java.util.List, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:4440)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(android.app.ClientTransactionHandler, android.os.IBinder, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions) (ActivityResultItem.java:49)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
    at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:193)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:858)D/AWSMobileClient: _federatedSignIn: Putting provider and token in store W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClientStore.set(java.util.Map)' on a null object reference W/System.err:     atcom.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient._federatedSignIn(AWSMobileClient.java:1448)
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.federatedSignIn(AWSMobileClient.java:1358)
    at com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.signInToAws(MainActivity.java:59)
    at com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.handleGoogleSiginInIntent(MainActivity.java:86)
    at com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:78)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7462)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4391)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4440)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)E/InternalCallback: Duplicate call to execute code.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error, duplicate call
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback.async(InternalCallback.java:93)
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.federatedSignIn(AWSMobileClient.java:1358)
    at com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.signInToAws(MainActivity.java:59)
    at com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.handleGoogleSiginInIntent(MainActivity.java:86)
    at com.thugdroid.awstest.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:78)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7462)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4391)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4440)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
Process: com.thugdroid.awstest, PID: 27446 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.amazonaws.mobile.client.Callback.onError(java.lang.Exception)' on a null object reference
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback.call(InternalCallback.java:77)
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback.access$000(InternalCallback.java:34)
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback$1.run(InternalCallback.java:103)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27446 SIG: 9 Application terminated.
```

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you found the solution?

Answer (score 6):

resolved by adding this dependency to `build.gradle`(app)

```
implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoauth:2.15.+@aar') { transitive=true }
```